# EF, UWP and SQLite. Which packages to choose

Tags: .net, entity-framework, sqlite, uwp

I am starting with my first attempt to create an UWP program that will be running on a Raspberry PI 3. The Pi is up and running with Windows 10 IoT Core and my 'Hello world' program has been deployed perfectly.

I need some data storage and I think the best choice would be a SQLite database in combination with the Entity Framework.

I see so many possible packages flying around that my head starts spinning. Articles from Microsoft with different approaches and versions and frameworks like .Net Standard and .Net Core. I am lost. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You'd better follow the UWP MSDN official document to make your app with SQLite database.

> We recommend that you use either the Entity Framework Core or the open-source [SQLite library](https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/) built by Microsoft.

If you want to use Entity Framework Core, see [Getting started with EF Core on Universal Windows Platform (UWP) with a New Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started).

If you want to use [SQLite library](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite?view=msdata-sqlite-2.0.0), you could read [Set up your solution to use the Microsoft.Data.SQlite library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases#set-up-your-solution-to-use-the-microsoftdatasqlite-library) for more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am up and running with SQLite, EF on UWP. I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M0sk0_4LJ9A) video on YouTube and this guy tells exactly (among a lot of trial and error) what has to be installed including the Add-Migration from the tools. I've installed the following packages from Nuget:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 1.1.15
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 1.1.15
- Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore.Tools 1.1.15

Also notice that I did not install the latest versions of these packages. They did not work for my project. Maybe someone can tell us why that is?

Comment: BTW I tried adding 4 images of my installed packages but the editor complained there was badly formatted code in my post and refused to add the images.